# Why does Masha address Wild-Eye as "Parmuska"?

Tags: translation, finnish-language, katja-kettu, the-midwife

In *The Midwife* by Katja Kettu, the central character, Wild-Eye, rescues a young Skolt girl named Masha from being killed by the SS. For the rest of the book, Masha addresses Wild-Eye as "Parmuska".

From context, I assumed that "Parmuska" was a term of respect that a young girl might use to address an older woman. But looking though Finnish dictionaries hasn't turned the word up. There is a complication in that Masha spoke her native language as well as Finnish, and so "Parmuska" may come from that. We are not explicitly told what her native tongue is, however, although it would be plausible for it to be some form of [Sámi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%A1mi_languages). Other words she speaks include:

> **Da, da**, Masha eagerly assured me, and told me her **Babushka** used to
> make her a kite every year at around this time.
>
> Why?
>
> “**Den razdeniya**. Birthday,“ she told me.

The "da" and "Babushka" seem Russian, but "den razdeniya" doesn't (Google Translate suggests Bulgarian). Another phrase she says:

> "The sorrel was in blossom when they found me in the woods. **Miehcest
> von tam kavnim**, my Babushka used to say.”

cannot be translated by Google Translate.

My question is, what does "Parmuska" mean, and what language is it from?

[Just to confirm, "Parmuska" does occur in the original Finnish text, i.e. it was not introduced in the process of translating the book to English. For example, Masha's plaintive request, "Parmuska, will you make me a kite?" is the translation from "Parmuska, tehet sie minule leijan?"]

Comment: "пармушка" and "мичест вон там кавним" do return something meaningful in Google Translate Ukrainian->English. "Masha", "Babushka", "Den razdeniya" - my first thought was ru, but it's not so with "Miehcest von tam kavnim".

Comment: [This Finnish Wikipedia page](https://fi.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hieroja-Priita) contains the word _Parmuska_, as well as an 'i.e.' and translation that equate them to the Swedish words _barnmorska_ and _lapsenpäästäjä_ which mean 'midwife' and 'babysitter'. Would that fit the context?

Comment: Wild-Eye definitely *is* a midwife, although the term used in the title of the book is "Kätilö". Is "parmuska" an alternative term for "kätilö"? "Babysitter" would also work in context, although Masha is 13 years old (maybe a bit too old for a babysitter).

Comment: The Wikipedia article I linked in my very strangely worded comment includes "kätilönä," which looks like some inflected version of "kätilö"...

Comment: I think you're right @CDR - the Danish translation ("Jordemoderen") has a glossary at the back,  https://books.google.es/books?id=zDulCAAAQBAJ&pg=PT193&lpg=PT193&dq=%22Jordemoderen%22+google+books+%22parmuska%22&source=bl&ots=3igX_-P1OK&sig=ACfU3U3Nl9P2LMnAUfsJbafyYCNipGY2MQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi6qKfEkeSEAxWRTqQEHde4AMQQ6AF6BAgOEAM#v=onepage&q&f=false and defines "parmuska" as "from the Swedish barnmorska, i.e. midwife". Do you want to write an answer?

Comment: As a Finn I had never heard the word "parmuska" before, but according to that wikipedia page, it's indeed another word for midwife, from Swedish barnmorska. It does sound like a typical Swedish loan especially in western Finnish dialects. "Lapsenpäästäjä" is another old-fashioned word that means a midwife (literally a "child-releaser"). No idea where "babysitter" came from; google translate? The modern Finnish word for a midwife is "kätilö".

Comment: I'll write one in a bit - thanks for finding that other reference. (Also, @Dronir - that's really useful!)

Comment: "but "den razdeniya" doesn't (Google Translate suggests Bulgarian)"  — it is russian, "день рождения", if you write it down by sound alone, and you're not native russian speaker, and your language lack palatization and sound for "ж". Btw, in bulgarian it would be "рожден ден" — "rozhden den".

Comment: @user28434 Thanks, that's good to know. Can you also interpret the "Miehcest von tam kavnim" line?

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez it's a bit harder, "von tam" is definitely "over there/yonder", "Miehcest" is a noun and the subject of the sentence. But can't tell what the word supposed to be. If it's about the time of the year it could be "[месяц](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/месяц#Russian)". But kinda doesn't make sense here. As for "kavnim" — absolutely no idea, can't even tell if it's a object or a verb of the sentence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Parmuska* means midwife; according to [this](https://journal.fi/virittaja/article/view/34783) glossary of terms associated with midwifery, it's a "suomi" (Finnish) word. Originally, though, it comes from Swedish.

[This 1909 publication](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Viritt%C3%A4j%C3%A4/oMo9AQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=RA1-PA34&printsec=frontcover) has a list of loanwords used in Finnish, including *parmuska*, which is apparently originally Swedish:

> [barnmorska](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/barnmorska) > *paarmuoska, paarmuska* = [kätilö](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/k%C3%A4til%C3%B6)

Both *barnmorska* and *kätilö* seem to refer to women who assist in childbirth.

---

The word comes under a section containing loanwords used around Kuopio, which is not in Lapland (where the story takes place). But, as the author of the book notes, the words in his list are...

> *joita käytetään kuopion tienoilla ja luullakseni suureksi osaksi muuallakin Suomessa*
>
> that are used around Kuopio, and, I believe, largely also elsewhere in Finland.